# Zend DB Table doesn't see the FROM clause

Tags: zend-framework

I have a Zend DB Table class that wraps my Country table.  When I create a select object off it though it tells me that there is no FROM clause in my SQL statement.  Here's the code:

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Countries();
$rows = $table->fetchAll($table->select()->columns(array('id', 'name')));       
$countryList = (array) $rows;
```

If I include ->from('Countries') immediately after the ->select(), it says the 'select query can not join with another table'.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I know it sounds like a dumb question but, did you specify the protected $_name variable in the Application_Model_DbTable_Countries class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the columns command you have to specify the table with a from call like so

```
$rows = $table->fetchAll($table->select()->from( 'tablename')->columns(array('id', 'name')));
```

I'm not exactly sure why but i think it's cuz once you start using the columns call and constructing your own selects, Zend assumes that you might be doing joins and other magic.

It'll give you that error even if you specify the $_name  variable in the table class.

I believe you can also do the following :

```
$rows = $table->fetchAll($table->select(true)->columns(array('id', 'name')));
```

This will tell the select to include the table from the table class.

Comment: No, problem Kim. I'm gonna assume that the second approach helped. I only say that because in your post it says that you tried the first approach I mentioned but it wasn't working.